# periodically do work or exit in python coroutine/task

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-asyncio

Completely new to python. I wanna write a simple async function that does a `ps $pid` every N seconds until it receives a stop signal.
i.e in go it'd simply be:

```
go func(cancelCtx context.Context) {
 ticker, cancel := time.NewTicker(time.Second)
 defer cancel()
 looper:
   for {
     select {
       case <-ticker.C:
         checkProcess()
       case <-ctx.Done():
         break looper
      }
    }
 fmt.Println("exited")
}(ctx)
```

I'm slowly ramping up on python asyncio but hoping to at least get some general guidance on the best pythonic approach. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To run tasks concurrently, you can achieve similar functionality using the asyncio module along with `asyncio.create_task()`.

```
import asyncio
import os

async def check_process(pid):
    while True:
        # Check if process is still running
        if not os.path.exists(f"/proc/{pid}"):
            print(f"Process with PID {pid} not found.")
            break
        else:
            print(f"Process with PID {pid} found.")
        
        # Wait for N seconds
        await asyncio.sleep(5)  # Change 5 to your desired interval

async def main():
    pid = 12345  # Replace 12345 with your PID
    task = asyncio.create_task(check_process(pid))
    await task

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```